# Calculus I - Ballon Variation when perforated by a needle

Tags: calculus, derivatives, spherical-trigonometry

A spherical balance is pierced by a needle so that its volume comes to
decrease a rate of $50\, \mathrm{cm}^3 / \mathrm{min}$. Determine an index of variation of your surface area on the
moment when the balloon radius is $15$ cm.
I have tried:
$$ V = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3.$$
Then I did the derivative of it:
$$ V' = 4\pi r^2.$$
But I don't know what to do with the $50\, \mathrm{cm}^3 / \mathrm{min}$ to find the aswer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac {dV}{dt} = 4\pi r^2 \frac {dr}{dt}$

$\frac {dV}{dt}$ is the rate that the volume is changing. i.e. $50 \frac {\text{cm}^3}{\text{sec}}$

$\frac {dr}{dt}$ is the rate at which the radius is changing, and what you need to solve for.

$50 \frac {\text{cm}^3}{\text{sec}} = 4\pi(15 \text{ cm})^2\frac {dr}{dt}$

Comment: I would need to pass 4π(15 cm)2 to the other side and let dr/dt at the other?

Comment: that is it... $\frac {dr}{dt} = \frac {50}{900\pi} \frac {\text{cm}}{\text {s}}$

Comment: Is that it, like, that the answer?

Comment: Not quite.  They have asked how fast the surface area is changing.  We have only soveld for the change in radius so far.  $A = 4\pi r^2, \frac {dA}{dt} = 8\pi r\frac {dr}{dt} = (8\pi)(15)(\frac {50}{900\pi})\frac {\text{cm}^2}{s}$

Comment: The answer should be 6.667pi cm2/s? Thanks!